# CSWP to show SPS2013 List Item

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, cswp

I`m using CSWP for the first time and tried with basic and advanced mode.
But cant find anything that can help to get specific Item from SPS2013 List.
Please suggest what should be the search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to return items from a specific list, switch to the Advanced 
Mode and in the query text, you enter the following: (this is the link to a list in my environment called Ahmed)

```
path:"https://ahmed.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/Lists/Ahmed"  (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)
```

(contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True) means to return only list items or documents

if this list has a custom content type, your query can be adjusted to be

```
path:"https://ahmed.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/Lists/Ahmed"  ContentTypeId:<Content Type GUID>
```

Comment: I tried with (contentclass:STS_ListItem) as only want to display items and not documents, still no good. BTW its data pulled from Announcement SPS 2013 List, hope that doesn't makes any difference?

Comment: Do you have items in the Announcement list (sorry I had to ask this one)? the Is search working at all on the site? Can you use your search center to look for the items in the announcements lists?

Comment: Interesting it doesn't throws any search, though I have 6 items under Announcement List. On the other side, Full content source Crawl is done and reindexed the Announcement list.

Comment: so based on what you are saying, it is a search issue that need to be fixed, and once it is working again, the CSWP should be returning the results back.

Comment: you are correct. I`ve resolved the search issue, but reinitializing the full crawl and now in general search can see result from the announcement list. Also it pulls information in CSWP too.  How can I just show the Body of the message, as of now it provides just the link, wherein I want to show the body content directly (don't want user to click on the url to see the content)

Comment: the only way to do that is by using a custom display template. You can use one of the default display template (i.e. item_twolines.html) and customize it (rename the file and change the title) and make sure to create a managed property for the body column, and use this managed property in your custom template. I know it might sound like a lot of work, but once you read about this topic and follow a step by step tutorial, it will become a second nature to you.